# Use count in create_distplot Python

Tags: python, numpy, plotly

I would like to use count as the y-axis instead of density as a percentage, as shown in the plot with code below:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

# Add histogram data
x1 = np.random.randn(200) - 2
x2 = np.random.randn(200)
x3 = np.random.randn(200) + 2
x4 = np.random.randn(200) + 4

# Group data together
hist_data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4']

# Create distplot with custom bin_size
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=.2)
fig.show()
```

[image]

I tried adding the argument `histnorm= ''`, which did change y-axis to count:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
fig = go.Figure()
# Add histogram data
x1 = np.random.randn(200) - 2
x2 = np.random.randn(200)
x3 = np.random.randn(200) + 2
x4 = np.random.randn(200) + 4

# Group data together
hist_data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4']

# Create distplot with custom bin_size
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=.2, histnorm= '')
fig.show()
```

However it had the line chart removed:
[image]

Is there a way to change the y-axis to count without altering the other parts of the plot, eg., the line chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `hist=''` output again, I noticed that the kde curve is not deleted, it just appears to be straightened and deleted due to the increased y-axis value. So by changing the height of the graph size, the curve can be seen.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

# Add histogram data
x1 = np.random.randn(200) - 2
x2 = np.random.randn(200)
x3 = np.random.randn(200) + 2
x4 = np.random.randn(200) + 4

# Group data together
hist_data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4']

# Create distplot with custom bin_size
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=.2, histnorm='')
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, height=800)# update

fig.show()
```

[image]